# Best laptop to seamlessly remote/stream my desktop PC anywhere in my home

Tags: laptop, cheap

I'm looking for a relatively cheap laptop (under 500 USD) that's thin and light so that I can remote/stream my desktop PC from anywhere inside my home network. I can hardwire into my network from anywhere so ideally the laptop would have an ethernet port. I would like the laptop to be powerful enough but not needlessly overkill because the only thing I want it to do is stream games/apps from my desktop. I'm wondering if a cheap Chromebook can do the job, but I would like the experience to be as low latency as possible, so a decent network card is required. Pretty much I would use this laptop as a monitor and keyboard connected to my desktop.

Also, I know this isn't the place, but if anyone knows the best software to use to seamlessly remote into a home network computer with close to zero latency, that would be much appreciated.

TL:DR requirements:

- thin and light
- good network card
- ethernet port great to have but not required
- cheap and not overkill
- Ideally screen is 15" but 13" will work too
- no preference on CPU manufacturer, GPU obviously can be low end onboard that can handle remote/streaming

Comment: The answer to your off-topic question is extremely relevant to the "best" hardware to run that software. I would figure that information out before asking for a recommendation, since streaming softwares may utilize specific GPU or CPU features for video decoding. The "network card" is usually one of a few common chipsets that almost every laptop use these days and there is not a significant difference in latency between them. The router performance will be much more important for keeping latency low.